# How tu upload JSON Array Object data via Bulk API

Tags: json, salesforce, bulk, dataloader

I have gone through salesforce documentation for bulk API 2.0 and it didn't support the Content-Type to be JSON

Now I have seen content type to be  JSON in the bulk API 1.0 or simply bulk API.

but I haven't seen any documentation on how to achieve this.

Please correct me if I am wrong about bulk API 2.0. and let me know how can I achieve that?

Answer (score 0):

Starting here:

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_asynch.meta/api_asynch/datafiles_xml_preparing.htm

There are many examples in the next few pages. Click next